# extract labels from labelled data frame

Tags: r

i want to extract label from the labelelled column from the database. so here i want to extract labels from columns all, vs1, am1 from the data df.

output can be a list of labels ("all","version","amp")

```
library(expss)     
df <- mtcars 
df$vs<-factor(df$vs, levels=c(1,0), labels = c("version","others")) 
df$am<-factor(df$am, levels=c(1,0), labels = c("AMP","others")) 
 
 
df$all<- 1 
df$vs1<-ifelse(df$vs=='version',1,NA) 
df$am1<-ifelse(df$am == 'AMP', 1, NA) 
 
 
#"Cuts will be labelled like below definition" 
 
val_lab(df$all)<-c("All"=1) 
val_lab(df$vs1)<-c("version"=1) 
val_lab(df$am1)<-c("AMP"=1) 
 
dfl <- list(df$all,df$vs1,df$am1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `sapply` you could do:

```r
library(expss)

dfl <- df[c("all", "vs1", "am1")]

sapply(dfl, function(x) names(val_lab(x)))
#>       all       vs1       am1 
#>     "All" "version"     "AMP"
```

Comment: this i can do , but how to extract directly from the database

Comment: What do you mean by database? According to your example data you have a dataframe.

Comment: i mean i need a output of vector like c("ALL", "Version", "AMP")

Comment: What my code returns is a vector or to be more precise a named vector. But  you could get rid of the names using e.g. `unname()`.